# How to change default port number in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Due to security reason I can't use the default mongodb port (27017). I need to change this default port number.

Comment: Surely you have googled it and tried some of the solutions found there? What problems are you having specifically?

Comment: you can start mongod process with --port parameter.

Comment: I am new in mongo db and linux .. i found so many solution .but it did not work. i did not able to find the conf file location in linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if port is already open and used by another application or service:

```
Linux: netstat -lptn
```

open mongo.conf file

```
vi /etc/mongod.conf
```

change the net section

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 8080
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1  # Listen to local interface only, comment to listen on all interfaces.
```

After changing run this command

```
mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

`/etc/mongod.conf` this will your config file location

Answer (score 3):

You can change it by changing the default port in your mongo.conf file.

follow these steps to change the port

1. `cd /etc` // go to this directory
2. `sudo vim mongo.conf` // this will open the mongo config file for you in terminal now u can edit the `port` over there and set whatever you want
3. Press **i** to edit then **ctrl + c** then **wq** to save.
4. Dont forget to restart mongo service `sudo mongo server restart`